# Thermocouples - to determine temperature use equation or tables?

Tags: thermocouple

I am building a controller based around J-type thermocouples designed to go to 500 degC. To convert voltage to temperature I can either use a linear equation, or table lookup. The lookup is, I assume, more accurate, but by how much (best/worst case)?

Comment: Plug it into excel and see...

Comment: @Trevor Time is money, which is why I hoped somebody knew a quick answer

Comment: It really depends on the quality of the table and the accuracy of the equation though Dirk. If the table is created using the equation then granularity of the table can be a factor. But all in all not a simple answer that anyone on this forum can really answer. As I say, your best answer is "do the math."

Comment: @Trevor I did a 3 point calculation and table comparison and got an error of 1.13 degC @ 245 degC. Good enough, probably

Comment: You are going to have to generate the tables from equations (unless you calibrate). Its not a question of accuracy, its a question of computation. If you can't afford the memory then you use the equation. If your restricted to fixed point, a table might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had the table or equation, that would certainly be helpful.

If you don't know the precise equation, I suggest plotting the table in a graphing calculator as a scatterplot (or in other software, even Excel if you know what you are doing) and observing the type of regression the graph looks like (linear, exponential, logarithmic, quadratic, etc). Then, use the appropriate regression equation function (linear regression, quadratic regression, etc) on your calculator to let your calculator calculate your equation. A quick search will tell you how to do this on whatever graphing calculator you have. Then, you can use your equation to make a program (if you know coding), or to make a function in Excel, or use your graphing calculator, to calculate values quickly.

If you don't like that idea, there is a function in Excel called "VLOOKUP" that may prove useful. It's been a while since I used it, but I belive it looks up values in a vertical table (there is also an HLOOKUP function for horizontal tables) and returns corresponding values (must be located on the right) defined by the user.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. It looks slightly parabolic, but since I only need +/- 2 degC accuracy I will treat it as linear, for now.

Comment: http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/temperature-measurement/thermocouple/type-j-calibration-table

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to use the [NIST polynomial](https://srdata.nist.gov/its90/download/type_j.tab), which seems ludicrously accurate